# Javascript: Only letters and numbers allowed

Tags: javascript

```
    function f_check_NumOrLett(form){    //Only letters and numbers allowed  

        var text = form.bucketname.value;
        alert(text);

        var filter = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
        if (filter.test(text)) {
            form.submit(); 
        } else {
            form.bucketname.select();
            alert("Only Allow letters and numbers!");
        }
    }
```

When I use this function, alert(text) can work, but it cannot neither submit the form or alert "Only allow letters and numbers" message. It seems it didn't excute IF condition.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "it cannot access into if condition". Can you make it clearer ?

Comment: what task are you trying to accomplish? what have you done so far to try and solve the task? why didn't your approach work?

Comment: I don't see how it could fail between the first alert and the if blocks. Can you build a fiddle ? Are you sure you don't have intermediate code ?

Answer (score 6):

If you're cool with supporting *new* browsers and no *legacy*, you can use the new `pattern` attribute which is available on `input elements` (which I think you're using here)

Example:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]"/>
```

The `pattern` attribute takes a normal *regular expression syntax*. Additionally, you can add the `required` (boolean) attribute, which indicates what a *form submit* will only work if the pattern is fulfilled.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]" required/>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I bet it would be because although this is a great solution for what they're trying to do, it doesn't solve their immediate problem for why the script doesn't work. I think using `pattern` is great, but it doesn't allow for too much customization in script - it's nice for normal form submissions though

Comment: How can it be a downvote. Even if doesn't solve the immediate problem (which it might will even) its a great alternative which works. Its not like totally out of context or wrong.

Comment: No reason to be mad at me. I was trying to explain why someone _might_ downvote this. It is a great **alternative** but people don't always like alternatives. I agree, it's not out of context or wrong at all. But like I said, it doesn't solve the problem, which people want first. It's easier for them to fix the one or two lines in their script than to refactor to use HTML5 attributes and validation. I'm not sure which I'd go with, that's not the point though

Comment: @jAndy I'm in agreement. There are lots of dev's that don't know about `pattern` and that it's an alternative to writing regex functions. I'd rather see your answer than not. It's valuable.

Comment: @Ian: I'm not mad at you :-)

Comment: Haha okay, I just wanted to be clear I wasn't trying to side with the downvoter, I was just trying to explain their nonsense :) I definitely agree with @nickhar, it's definitely worth it to have this as an answer