# Javascript Regex input text letters and numbers only

Tags: javascript

I'm using this script to only allow my input text letters and numbers

```
function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {
       textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
              if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
                this.oldValue = this.value;
                this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
                this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
                console.log("If 1");
              } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
                this.value = this.oldValue;
                this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
                console.log("if 2");
              } else {
                  console.log("if 3");
                this.value = "";
              }
            });
          });
    }
    
    setInputFilter(document.getElementById("frm_nuevo_proveedor:j_idt35"), function(value) {
          return /^[^\W_]+$/i.test(value); 
    });
```

My problem is that once I type the first value it doesn't let me erase it anymore

[image: Example]

So the first value won't let me delete it.

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13804995/1772933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you attempt to remove the last character, the RegExp returns false because it is not set to accept blank strings. This causes the script to restore the **oldValue**, which would be that single letter.

The simplest fix seems to be updating the RegExp used as the filter. This should work for you, though I'm no expert on regular expressions so there may be a better way:

```
setInputFilter(document.getElementById("testEl"), function(value) {
  return /(^$|^[^\W_]+$)/i.test(value);
});
```

Comment: Yes that is that gave me solution thank you =)